# How to train Word2Vec model on Wikipedia page using gensim?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec

After reading [this article](https://codesachin.wordpress.com/2015/10/09/generating-a-word2vec-model-from-a-block-of-text-using-gensim-python/), I start to train my own model. The problem is that the author does not make it clear what the `sentences` in  `Word2Vec` should be like.

I download the text from a Wikipedia page, as it is written is the article, and I make a list of sentences from it:

```
sentences = [word for word in wikipage.content.split('.')]
```

So, for example, `sentences[0]` looks like:

```
'Machine learning is the subfield of computer science that gives computers the ability to learn without being explicitly programmed'
```

Then I try to train a model with this list:

```
model = Word2Vec(sentences, min_count=2, size=50, window=10,  workers=4)
```

But the dictionary of the model consists of letters! For example, the output of `model.wv.vocab.keys()` is:

```
dict_keys([',', 'q', 'D', 'B', 'p', 't', 'o', '(', ')', '0', 'V', ':', 'j', 's', 'R', '{', 'g', '-', 'y', 'c', '9', 'I', '}', '1', 'M', ';', '`', '\n', 'i', 'r', 'a', 'm', '–', 'v', 'N', 'h', '/', 'P', 'F', '8', '"', '’', 'W', 'T', 'u', 'U', '?', ' ', 'n', '2', '=', 'w', 'C', 'O', '6', '&', 'd', '4', 'S', 'J', 'E', 'b', 'L', '$', 'l', 'e', 'H', '≈', 'f', 'A', "'", 'x', '\\', 'K', 'G', '3', '%', 'k', 'z'])
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The input to the `Word2Vec` model object could be a list of list of words, using the tokenization function in `nltk`:

```
>>> import wikipedia
>>> from nltk import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
>>> page = wikipedia.page('machine learning')
>>> sentences = [word_tokenize(sent) for sent in sent_tokenize(page.content)]
>>> sentences[0]
['Machine', 'learning', 'is', 'the', 'subfield', 'of', 'computer', 'science', 'that', 'gives', 'computers', 'the', 'ability', 'to', 'learn', 'without', 'being', 'explicitly', 'programmed', '.']
```

And feed it in:

```
>>> from gensim.models import Word2Vec
>>> model = Word2Vec(sentences, min_count=2, size=50, window=10,  
>>> list(model.wv.vocab.keys())[:10]
['sparsely', '(', 'methods', 'their', 'typically', 'information', 'assessment', 'False', 'often', 'problems']
```

But in general, an generator (of sentence) that contains a generator (of words) would work too, i.e.:

```
>>> from gensim.utils import tokenize
>>> paragraphs = map(tokenize, page.content.split('\n')) # paragraphs
>>> model = Word2Vec(paragraphs, min_count=2, size=50, window=10,  workers=4)
>>> list(model.wv.vocab.keys())[:10]
['sparsely', 'methods', 'their', 'typically', 'information', 'assessment', 'False', 'often', 'problems', 'symptoms']
```

Comment: Is there a way to effectively remove punctuation directly in the comprehension `[word_tokenize(sent) for sent in sent_tokenize(page.content)]`?

Comment: Use `gensim.utils.tokenize`.  instead of `word_tokenize`. `[gensim.utils.tokenize(sent) for sent in sent_tokenize(page.content)]`

Comment: Thank you! However, as I've learned, output of `tokenize` should be wrapped in a `list`: `[list(gensim.utils.tokenize(sent)) for sent in sent_tokenize(text)]`.

Comment: Generators whenever possible, minimize `list()` usage. Btw, did you read the second part of the answer? `map(tokenize, page.content.split('\n'))` and `map(tokenize, sent_tokenize(page.content))` would also work.